# Add a space between image and line in header

Tags: graphics, header-footer

--- EDIT 2 ---

I've created the following header using an image editor to help you guys understand what I'm trying to do.
[image: This is what I'm trying to do.]

--- End of EDIT 2 ---

--- EDIT 1 ---

This is closer to what I have in my header. Only instead of actually writing "Chapter 1" and "Subsection", I'm using \rightmark and \leftmark, but the result is basically the same. And, of course, I'm using a different image.
The problem is with the line crossing the image. Or maybe with the length of the header line.

--- End of EDIT 1 ---

Ok, I think I've searched for this everywhere and I can't come up with an answer. Does anybody know how to put a space between the image and the header line, so that the line doesn't cross the image?
This is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% ---------------------------- Header ---------------------------- %
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase{Subsection 1.1}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\MakeUppercase{Chapter 1}}
\fancyhead[L]{\raisebox{-.6\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}}
% ---------------------------- Footer ---------------------------- %
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Just use `\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]`.

Comment: @Bernard... Is there a `\rasebox` needed at all for this purpose? I didn't used one for my answer but I am not really good on `fancyhdr` usage... So, I would like to know if I should use a `\raisebox` and why. (If you think that a comment on that is related to the question and thus good to be provided here)

Comment: For me, \ raisebox` is here to have the possibility to use the height and depth optional arguments, but there are of course other possibilities. However beware not to have warning abou headheight.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard.... I thought it would possibly help elsewhere too... But of course this could be help in other header commands... Thanks!

Comment: The \raisebox is there to put the image in the same line as the header, not above it.
But thanks anyway for all the answers so far!!

Comment: Could you post a code with the real header text?

Comment: @Bernard, thanks a lot for your help!! I've changed the code to something closer to what I'm using. I hope this helps!

Comment: If I understand correctly, the axis of the image should be, as much as possible, the same as the axis of the box containing the header?

Comment: I've uploaded an image as an example to make it easier. I'm trying to make something like this https://i.imgur.com/GCkT6re.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution redefines `\headrule` to fine-tune its placement:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% ---------------------------- Header ---------------------------- %
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase{Subsection 1.1}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\MakeUppercase{Chapter 1}}
\fancyhead[L]{\raisebox{-.7\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}}
% ---------------------------- Footer ---------------------------- %
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hspace*{1.2cm}\rule[2ex]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.2cm}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `\vspace` after your `\includegraphics` should do the trick. No razebox needed:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% ---------------------------- Header ---------------------------- %
\fancyhead{} % blank \fancyhead command which clears all the header fields.%
% --------- The lines below are commented because I'm using in the original file, but I think that there is no need for it in here. ---------
% \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
% \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
% \markboth{#1}{}}
%    \fancyhead[CO,CE]{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}\vspace{3pt}}
% ---------------------------- Footer ---------------------------- %
\fancyfoot{} %Clears the footer fields using a blank \fancyfoot command.%
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage} % makes the page number appear on the right of the footer for an even page and the right for an odd. The \thepage command returns the page number of the page it's used on.
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```